# How do I transform this Probability in weak law of large number form?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_{1},\dots$ be a sequence of independent random variables. Suppose, for $k=1,2,\dots$ $$P\left(X_{2k-1}=1\right)=P\left(X_{2k-1}=-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and the probability density function of $X_{2k}$ is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\sqrt{2}|x|},\,\,\ -\infty<x<\infty$$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} P\left(\frac{X_{1}+\dots+X_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}} \ge 1 \right)$ is

1. $\Phi(1)$
2. $\frac{1}{2}$
3. $\Phi(-1)$
4. $1$

where $\Phi(a)$ denotes the cdf of standard normal at $a$.

The question looks like it related to *WLLN* but I am not able to figure how to use that theorem we can separate the odd and even random variables but they suggested probabilities for odd ones only for $1$ and $-1$ (do they can not take any other value, I think they can) and the distribution given from it the $E(X_{2k}) =0$ since it is symmetric what to do next how to proceed with this problem. I am having trouble in understanding the context.

Comment: This seems to be more related to the central limit theorem. The weak law of large number is a statement about the $L^2$ convergence to the expectation.

Comment: Simplest approach: split the sum into the sum of odd numbered and even numbered terms, apply the most classical central limit theorem to each of these two sub-sums, observe that they are independent, and conclude by noting that $\frac1{\sqrt2}(Z+Z')$ is standard normal if $Z$ and $Z'$ are independent and both standard normal.

Answer (score 2):

This is an application of the [Lyapunov (or Lindeberg) CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) for independent but not necessarily identically distributed random variables. To bring the expression in the form of the CLT note that the distribution of $X_{2k}$ it the Laplace distribution with parameters $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $μ=0$ (following the notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution)). Hence $E[X_{2k}]=μ=0$ and $Var(X_{2k})=2b^2=1$. An easy calculation shows that $E[X_{2k-1}]=0$ and $Var(X_{2k-1})=1$. So, although the $X_k$ are not identically distributed they all have mean $μ=0$ and standard deviation $σ=1$. Hence, turning back to the given expression write $$s^2_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}σ_i^2=2n \implies s_{2n}=\sqrt{2n}$$ and use the Lyapunov CLT which states that $$\frac{1}{s_{2n}}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(X_i-0)\overset{d}\to \mathcal N(0,1)\implies \frac{X_1+\dots+X_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}\overset{d}\to \mathcal N(0,1)$$ giving in your case that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}P\left(\frac{X_1+\dots+X_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}\ge 1\right)=1-\Phi(1)=\Phi(-1)$$
Of course it remains to check the Lyapunov (or the weaker Lindeberg) condition.

---

To check the Lyapunov condition, note that $|X_{2k}|\sim\exp(b^{-1})\implies |X_{2k}|\sim\exp(\sqrt{2})$. So $E[|X_{2k}|^m]=\frac{m!}{\sqrt{2}^m}$ and therefore choosing $δ=2$ yields $$\frac{1}{s_{2n}^{2+δ}}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}E\left[|X_i-μ_i|^{2+δ}\right]=\frac{1}{2n\cdot 2n}\left[\sum_{i=2k-1}^{2n}1+\sum_{i=2k}^{2n}\frac{4!}{\sqrt{2}^4}\right]=\frac{n+6n}{2n\cdot 2n}=\frac{7}{4n}\to 0$$ as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: For a simpler approach, see my comment on main.